# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Companion when using `influx-client-reactive` and `quarkus`

Tags: java, gradle, okhttp, quarkus, influxdb

Error occurs when instantiating a client

```
    InfluxDBClientReactive influxDBClient = InfluxDBClientReactiveFactory.create(
            influxConf.url(),
            influxConf.username(),
            influxConf.password().toCharArray());
```

dependency is excluded from `quarkus-bom`

```
implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}") {
    exclude group: "com.squareup.okhttp3", module: "okhttp"
}
implementation "com.influxdb:influxdb-client-reactive:6.4.0"
```

otherwise (3.x.x) is forced and would cause

```
'okhttp3.RequestBody okhttp3.RequestBody.create(java.lang.String, okhttp3.MediaType)'
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'okhttp3.RequestBody okhttp3.RequestBody.create(java.lang.String, okhttp3.MediaType)
```

at the same line.

trace:

```
Companion
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Companion
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.kt:70)
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.parse$okhttp(HttpUrl.kt:1239)
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Companion.get(HttpUrl.kt:1634)
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Companion.parse(HttpUrl.kt:1643)
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl.parse(HttpUrl.kt)
    at com.influxdb.client.InfluxDBClientOptions$Builder$ParsedUrl.<init>(InfluxDBClientOptions.java:689)
    at com.influxdb.client.InfluxDBClientOptions$Builder$ParsedUrl.<init>(InfluxDBClientOptions.java:681)
    at com.influxdb.client.InfluxDBClientOptions$Builder.connectionString(InfluxDBClientOptions.java:504)
    at com.influxdb.client.InfluxDBClientOptions$Builder.url(InfluxDBClientOptions.java:288)
    at com.influxdb.client.reactive.InfluxDBClientReactiveFactory.create(InfluxDBClientReactiveFactory.java:105)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-java/issues/121) led me to think that `com.squareup.okio:okio` might also play a role here.

```
com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2
\--- io.quarkus:quarkus-bom:2.11.2.Final
     \--- runtimeClasspath

com.squareup.okio:okio:3.0.0 -> 1.17.2
\--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0
```

That `Options.of` is a call to method in that dependency and not `Optional` from java. That there is nothing strange here other than some [quarkus necromancy](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/26068) forced for [fabric8io/kubernetes-client](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/12680)

```
exclude group: "com.squareup.okio", module: "okio"
```

from `quarkus-bom`

Answer (score 0):

So you have to override the `okhttp` being used by Selenium. the most important part of this is to override the `okio` artifact or exclude it, for me I felt it was safer to override it rather than exclude it. Hopefully you can convert my mvn to gradle.

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp-urlconnection</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
        <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```